# Order by id MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have here my code

```
$query=mysqli_query($dbcon,"select count(user_name) from `viewlist` where user_name='$_name'");
```

What I want to do is that it only shows columns with the username `$_name` but arrange it on the table descending through id (which is auto increment). I have tried ordered by id `DESC` but didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice question for MySQL: order by id or date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166752/best-practice-question-for-mysql-order-by-id-or-date)

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. If you're using the `COUNT` aggregator, without a `GROUP BY`, you're only going to get one result. Why would you need to order one result?

Comment: Forget about the php for now. Instead, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -2):

maybe..

```
$query=mysqli_query($dbcon,"select tb.* from (select count(user_name) as total from `viewlist` group by user_name) as tb order by tb.total desc");
```